# From/at in contexts like the one given

Tags: prepositions

Where did you get this book?

I got it **from** the store right across the mall.

Or

I got it **at** the store right across the mall.

In contexts like this, are **from** and **at** interchangeable? Do both the sentence get the same meaning across?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both **at** and **from** in this sentence can be used to convey or give the same meaning. A native listener would understand your meaning in both cases.

The preposition **at** is usually used to talk about something very exact or specific (time, place) and so it's possible that your sentence with **at** might be used when the speaker is actually physically pointing towards the store as he speaks. i.e. being very specific.

In comparison **from** might be used when the speaker is sitting at home and telling his family where he bought his item from. i.e. being more general.

Answer (score 0):

They are both acceptable and commonly used in this context.

I can't imagine any difference in meaning or connotation.  I'd say that **from** is a slightly more proper word to use here and **at** is very slightly more casual.  You might be slightly more likely to write the former and say the latter.